# How do I match cell boundary to bounds of superview?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a `UICollectionViewController` and a `UICollectionViewCell`.

I would like to have a leading and trailing space from the bounds of the `UICollectionViewCell` to the bounds of the `UICollectionViewController` so when the orientation changes my cells will resize to the new horizontal bounds.

How is this done usually?

edit: I'm using `estimatedItemSize` to calculate sizes in my `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` if this helps.

Comment: The height/width of the `UICollectionViewCell ` and `UICollectionViewController ` will be same?

Comment: Well my intention is to do trailing space - 20 for spacing on the width and just worry about the width, not the height of the cell.

Answer (score 0):

Ok mostly solved it.  Because I'm using iOS 8's auto cell resizing (like `estimatedItemSize`) I need to implement `preferredLayoutAttributesFittingAttributes` in my cell.  Here's my implementation:

```
- (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes * _Nonnull)preferredLayoutAttributesFittingAttributes:(UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes * _Nonnull)layoutAttributes {
    UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *attr = [layoutAttributes copy];
    CGRect newFrame = attr.frame;
    self.frame = newFrame;

    [self setNeedsLayout];
    [self layoutIfNeeded];

    CGFloat desiredHeight = [self.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize].height;
    newFrame.size.height = desiredHeight;
    newFrame.size.width = _containerWidth - 20;
    attr.frame = newFrame;
    return attr;
}
```

where `_containerWidth` is a property in my cell.  I set my cell's `_containerWidth` in `cellForItemAtIndexPath` in my collectionview.

Although there's probably a more elegant way to do this, I just call `reloadData` on the collectionview during rotation.

I've temporarily given up on resizing cells for screen rotation as its so buggy, but this should suffice for the purposes of this question.  I'll leave this question open in case someone finds a better solution.